# What does [TYPE] mean in powershell

Tags: powershell, malware, deobfuscation

I'm currently working on deobfuscating a piece of powershell code used in a trickbot campaign.

I understand that the script is initializing a system directory object to create a new directory, but I don't understand what [TYPE] actually does or why it is required.

I have tried to google this, but I cant really find any satisfying answer.

```
Set-Item 'variAblE:8TKm0' ([TYPE]"system.io.directory");

(Get-Item 'variAblE:8TKm0').Value::"CreateDirectory"($HOME + "\Frv3p35\Ntwhagi\");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a data type: The most common DataTypes (type accelerators) used in PowerShell are listed below.

> [string]    Fixed-length string of Unicode characters
> [char]      A
> Unicode 16-bit character
> [byte]      An 8-bit unsigned character
>
> [int]       32-bit signed integer
> [long]      64-bit signed integer

> [bool]      Boolean True/False value
>
> [decimal]   A 128-bit decimal value
> [single]    Single-precision
> 32-bit floating point number
> [double]    Double-precision 64-bit
> floating point number
> [DateTime]  Date and Time
>
> [xml]       Xml object
> [array]     An array of values
> [hashtable]
> Hashtable object

[image]
ref: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html

Comment: So that means that this is a "Type"-object? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, Im not that familiar with Powershell

Comment: Type >> System.Object. I added a screenshot to my previous reply. Hope that answers it.